# Consolidate values from joined table into one value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Makes` and `Models`. I've created [a db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e0e6371b79da78f29725252849a82143) to make things easier.

They are created like so:

```
create table Makes (
    MakeId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    YearEstablished varchar(4) not null
);

create table Models (
    ModelId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    YearIntroduced varchar(4) not null,
    MakeId int foreign key references Makes(MakeId)
);
```

And they have data like this:

[image: data in tables]

**Desired Output**

I want to consolidate the `Models` into one value and have something like:

```
    make    | year_established |  models
------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------
 Volkswagen | 1937             | Golf (1974); Polo (1975); Passat (1973)
 Toyota     | 1937             | 4 or more models
```

So if there are 3 or less models, they get consolidated into one value as shown, but if it is 4 or more models, then it should simply be `4 or more models`. This way the car make is not duplicated.

I'd like the SQL to run on SQL Server (2017) and MySQL (version 5).

Comment: T-SQL and MySQL are very different dialects; the solution will be different for both. There are, however, many examples on [so] on how to achieve delimited results in both dialects. What about those answers didn't you understand?

Comment: mysql has group_concat Sql server has STRING_AGG, there is no answer for both

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Apologies @DaleK, it won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL and `STRING_AGG()` in SQL Server.

MySQL:

```
SELECT ma.Name as make,
       ma.YearEstablished as year_established,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(mo.id) >= 4
            THEN '4 or more models'
            ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' ', mo.Name, ' (', mo.YearIntroduced, ')')) END as models
  FROM Makes ma INNER JOIN Models mo ON ma.MakeId = mo.MakeId
 GROUP BY ma.Name, ma.YearEstablished;
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT ma.Name as make,
       ma.YearEstablished as year_established,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(mo.id) >= 4
            THEN '4 or more models'
            ELSE STRING_AGG(CONCAT(mo.Name, ' (', mo.YearIntroduced, ')'), ', ') END as models
  FROM Makes ma INNER JOIN Models mo ON ma.MakeId = mo.MakeId
 GROUP BY ma.Name, ma.YearEstablished;
```